# Magento 2.1 Override Catalog Inventory

Tags: magento-2.1, cataloginventory

I'm currently writing multi-vendor extension,
I'm looking for sample code on how to override the inventory, so it shows inventory from a custom field,
Already tried overriding getQty of the Product class but that doesn't work,

Any ideas would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Magento2 uses the \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface to get stock information of a product:

```
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());
```

You should create an own implementation of this enterface which could gets it's data from a custom field. Register your implementation with the di.xml file in a module.

Comment: When implementing an interface, do I need to implement all functions? or somehow only implement part of it and extending a class that implements the rest?